# Simple word replacement in output from SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4.

Is there a replace string function which can take an array of words, or other similar function?

Ex.

```
SELECT REPLACE(my_column, ['blue', 'red'], ['ColorBlue', 'ColorRed']);
```

So blue becomes ColorBlue, and red becomes ColorRed?
It's not only such simple replacements, but for the example I'm using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is create it:

```
create or replace function rep_arr(str text, src text[], rep text[])
returns text as $$
begin
    for i in 1..array_length(src, 1) loop
        str := replace(str, src[i], rep[i]);  
    end loop;
    return str;
end; $$ language plpgsql
```

Call:

```
select rep_arr('bla bla blue bla red bla', '{blue,red}' , '{ColorBlue,ColorRed}');
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @OtoShavadze that you can write your own function.

Here is my solution:

I use [`generate_subscripts(array anyarray, dim int)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS) function as suggested in [Searching in Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING) documentation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION translate(string text, from_array text[], to_array text[])
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    output  text;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO output
        to_array[idx] 
    FROM 
        generate_subscripts(from_array, 1) AS idx 
    WHERE 
        from_array[idx] = string;       -- here you can change the search condition

    IF FOUND THEN
        RETURN output;
    ELSE
        RETURN string;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

It finds and replaces whole words but you can change it (line marked in the code) to find only a substring, match case-insensitive, etc...

You should also add parameter checking: arrays should not be null, multidimensional nor differ in size:

```
IF from_array IS NULL OR to_array IS NULL THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'NULL parameters';
END IF;

IF array_ndims(from_array) != 1 OR array_ndims(to_array) != 1 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Multidimensional parameters';
END IF;

IF array_length(from_array, 1) != array_length(to_array, 1) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Parameters size differ';
END IF;
```

---

```
SELECT translate('red', ARRAY['blue', 'red'], ARRAY['ColorBlue', 'ColorRed']);
```

returns

```
ColorRed
```